# "Someone else's dream" - female voice, guitar

Tags: identify-this-song, record

I would like to know the name of this song. It's a recording that I found out there  https://soundcloud.com/user-738039642/song-2

Comment: Considering the recording quality, finding the song's name could be hard.

Comment: Did you notice it's from the same user as [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/5427/1456) of yours? Does that help?

Comment: I uploaded those songs

Comment: I thought this song was a cover of some song, but with SoundHound I did not get results.
I do not speak English, so I can hardly recognize the lyrics of the song. If someone writes the lyrics, it would also help me find it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a cover of the song ["Life in Mono"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KpODDuzlhk)

I was able to identify it from scraps of the lyrics:

> The stranger sang a theme
>   From someone else's dream
>   The leaves began to fall
>   And no one spoke at all
>   But I can't seem to recall
>   When you came along
>   Ingenue

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_in_Mono

Comment: Thank you very much :) . I was looking for this song for a long time